# How to add an object values in html elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to add an object values in multiple div elements but Im struggling to get the expected behaviour.

Here is my code :

```js
obj = {
  valeur1: "text1",
  valeur2: "text2",
  valeur3: "text3",
  valeur4: "text4"
}

$('div').each(function(i) {
  $.each(obj, function(index, value) {
    if (value in $('div')) {
      return
    } else {
      $('div').text(value);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I dont understand why I always get :

```
text4
text4
text4
text4
```

Please, can you explain me what is the problem with my algorithm ?

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `value in $('div')` to do. `$('div')` returns a jQuery object, so this tests whether `value` is one of the properties of that object.

Comment: `$('div').text(value)` sets the text of all `div` elements to `value`. What are you expecting it to do instead?

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get? `<div>text1</div><div>text2</div>...`?

Comment: @Barmar yes, im trying to get that result

Comment: @Barmar So I guess my algorithm is correct and the problem is related to if(value in $('div')?

Comment: No, your algorithm is all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = [
  "text1",
  "text2",
  "text3",
  "text4"
]

console.log(obj.length);

$('div').each(function(i) {
  this.innerHTML = obj[i];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Is the above model what you're using? You can easily just declare a string array, and iterate it as I've demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops. Use the index in the main loop to get the corresponding element of the property.

And you should be setting `$(this).text()`, not `$('div').text()`, since the latter sets the text of *all* DIVs, not the current element of the loop.

```js
obj = {
  valeur1: "text1",
  valeur2: "text2",
  valeur3: "text3",
  valeur4: "text4"
}

$('div').each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(obj['valeur' + (i+1)])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: What is the role of  'valeur' before (i+1) ?

Comment: @Azim, `valeur (i + 1)` to get the **valeur** property with each iteration, for example in the first iteration it would be `"valeur" + 0 + 1`, and that is `"valeur0"` and so on, but I think you should have used an array instead of an object to store those data, because I see there is no use of the property name.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping inside a loop. So whatever values you enter are being overwritten until the last loop.

One method to fix, like so:

```js
$(function() {
  var obj = {
    valeur1: "text1",
    valeur2: "text2",
    valeur3: "text3",
    valeur4: "text4"
  }

  var i = 0;

  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    $("div").eq(i++).html(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

In this example, iterating the Object itself. Since `$.each()` will give us the `key` and `value` pair, we can set a `index` variable to use in the loop. We can target the `<div>` element using `.eq()`.

Another like so:

```js
$(function() {
  var obj = {
    valeur1: "text1",
    valeur2: "text2",
    valeur3: "text3",
    valeur4: "text4"
  }

  $("div").each(function(i, el) {
    var k = Object.keys(obj);
    $(el).html(obj[k[i]]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

This one, we iterate the Elements. We get an `index` and `element` pair this time. Since we want to get specific matching elements from the Object, we can make an array of the Keys and use each in the loop.

Your pick.

Comment: The first example is very clear. Thank you very much for your help !